# Upload sliced filed to SPOnline document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to upload a large file to an SP online site using the StartUpload, ContinueUpload and FinishUpload methods on the File class as given in the link below. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint .

The code is provided below.

```
using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
       {
         // Call the start upload method on the first slice.
        bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
        fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
      }
```

I am getting an error

> "'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File' does not contain a definition for
>   'StartUpload' and no extension method 'StartUpload' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   \UploadSlicedFile\UploadSlicedFile\Program.cs".

T
he Microsoft.Client dll version added in the solution is 15.0.0.0. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: Use nuget in VS to get the latest version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

Comment: Thanks! It is now working after adding the new DLLs in the reference.